# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found

Tags: android, gradle

I have just installed Android Studio and after some quirks about the SDK Build Tools minimum having to be 19.1.0 instead of 19.0.3 I have not came about another error

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.
```

I haven't found a solution in google and I am absolutely new so I  "have no clue"...  the error shows up when I just created a new blank activity (and application).

What does the error means and how to fix it? (if it's a problem)

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646502/getting-build-failed-with-an-exception-android-studio-0-4-3-and-0-4-4

This post should solve you issue.

Comment: OK I managed to solve it by re installing the SDK build tools 19.0.3 from SDK manager. (I have deleted them before because I thought that the new version 19.1.0 would be enough (and it didnt came preinstalled for some reason)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Plugin with id 'android-library' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found)

Comment: if anyone had this issue take a look at my answer here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421430/plugin-with-id-android-not-found-android-studio/24464014#24464014

Comment: @ScottBarta: Not the same error, which means different solutions, so no duplicate here.

Answer (score 34):

Put below code in build.gradle file of main Application and sync it.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: this is wrong , this code is bringing other errors.

Comment: please provide proper explanation. Even if experienced developers can understand this, not new dev's can

Answer (score 1):

It Works, I just change gradle version to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'