# Plugin with id 'android' not found (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, project, installation

I recently just switched to Android Studio 0.6.1 for app dev and I ran into an issue with gradle.

I get `"Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.` I am quite new so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.b3dog.helloagain"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Do you see Android SDK attached to the project? It should be in external libraries. there should be Java JDK library as well.

Comment: I was using jdk version 1.6 and didn't change the bytecode. This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

this issue appears in my android studio 0.6.1 canary build so  after a week struggling i found whats wrong with new studio version . its not about Gradle as far as i see . and it happen to some people and you know why ? because some people specially junior developer accidentally proceeding in way that this error occur just after create new project . problem came from name of your activity let me explain it to your step by step

now , when u create new project , wizard appear and here's your step :

first :
       you enter application name 
second :
       select your minimum sdk 
third : 
       type of your activity
forth :
       your activity name

here's the point . if you choose the system default"my activity

[image]

error will occur but if you change it to your own custom name such as "myListactivity" or any other custom One . this error will no longer exist .

Comment: need to say that today i started another project and changed MyActivity (default) to mainActivity and its funny this error appeared again . then i tried myactivity and every hting went fine , if you choosed name start with capital and error occured then try with non capital ..

Answer (score -1):

Mostly it is because of that project sync error.

In android studio, please try that click  "tools" ->"Android"-> "sync project with gradles files."