# Android Studio Error: (8, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio (0.6.1) on OS X (10.9.3) and Gradle 1.1 using Brew (brew install gradle). However, I can't get my first Hello World! project... Please help me solve this issue

**build.gradle:**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'
    defaultConfig {}
    productFlavors {}
}

dependencies {
}
```

Error message:

> Error:(8, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found.

[Getting Build failed with an Exception Android Studio 0.4.3 and 0.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646502/getting-build-failed-with-an-exception-android-studio-0-4-3-and-0-4-4) post and [Android Studio: Plugin with id 'android-library' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found) post does not solves the problem...

[Second post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153739/android-studio-plugin-with-id-android-library-not-found) returns this error message:

> Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle. Please
>   use version 1.10. Please point to a supported Gradle version in the
>   project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if
>   applicable.) Fix Gradle wrapper and
>   re-import project Gradle settings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you have missed to add android gradle plugin dependency in `dependencies` block.

Replace the top `buildScript` section by this and sync your project with gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
 }

 apply plugin: 'android'

 android {
      compileSdkVersion 19
      buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId 'YOUR_APP_PACKAGE'
          minSdkVersion 9
          targetSdkVersion 17
      }
      buildTypes {
          release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
          }
      }
      productFlavors {   }
  }

  dependencies {

   }
```

Comment: Now I get this error `Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0` strange I followed [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093561/how-to-force-android-studio-0-6-0-to-use-sdk-build-tools-19-1-0) (second answer GUI one) On my GUI interface I don't have modules for some reason. (step 4)

Comment: Please check the updated answer and match with your build.gradle file.

Comment: sometimes the buildscript declaration can be in a separate file which may be deleted hence the problem.

Answer (score 3):

build.gradle file inside my "app" folder: PATH: /home/work/ProjectName/app/build.gradle

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}


 dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

 }
}
```

build.gradle file outside my "app" folder: PATH: /home/work/ProjectName/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Note after all these update synchronise your project with gradle file

Answer (score 2):

Put below code in build.gradle file of main Application and sync it.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Credit to [Ganesh Katikar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204436/error1-0-plugin-with-id-android-not-found/26114190#26114190)