# Android Studio Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, repository

I'm new to android studio and had somebody write an app I made which was originally used in app inventor. I followed his template and added new things. The app has a problem with the Gradle and gives me the following.

```
"Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found."
```

It also says that my extras Android Support Repository isn't installed however it is. and everything is up to date. I saw many things about updating the Gradle, How do I do that if the SDK manager didn't.

code is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "contactorganizer.introcode.or.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Sorry about not having much knowledge.
If you would like the project I can email it to you because I have absolutely no clue and would love to just build this.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24302833

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I updated my Android Studio to the latest, I got the same problem. Here is how I solved it.

**First:**
Add the following code to the top of your build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
} 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Second:** Find the gradle-wrapper.properties.
Change the last sentence to this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Just want to point out that the corresponding line in my gradle-wrapper.properties file has "https" not "http", so that if you are having problems, try both to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem too. The android plugin is 1.2.3. It appears when running one module task in the module directory like this way, `../graldew :module:xxx`.

I eventually notice plugin 1.2.3 cannot get right context and android plugin 1.5 works well. So It will  work to give it right gradle file.

```
../gradlew -b ../build.gradle  -c ../settings.gradle  :module:xxx
```

This is the situation for me. You can just regard it as a reference.