# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, gradle-experimental

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found
>   **i googled and searching since 3days but didn't get solution..... stuck totally **
>   i gradle version :2.5..
>   **build.gradle(projetc:android)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {

            applicationId =  "com.example.altaf.Android"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"


            buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    type = "int"
                    name = "VALUE"
                    value = "1"
                }
            }

        }

    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))

        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {

            applicationId = "com.app"
        }
    }



    // Configures source set directory.

    android.sources {

        main {

            java {

                source {

                    srcDir "src"

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0"
}
```

**build.gradle(module:opencvlibrary310)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal i formatted sir

Comment: @aezaz Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found this problem you are getting in build.gradle(module:opencvlibrary310) file?

Comment: @AnandSingh no in module:app file

Comment: @aezaz did you set ndk directory path in local.properties file? For ex: ndk.dir=C\:\\android-sdks\\ndk-bundle

Comment: @AnandSingh yes locally set

Comment: yes i have set it locally.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your `build.gradle(module:opencvlibrary310)` like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {

            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22

        }

    }
}
```

and I'm using below version of experimental gradle plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
```

**Update:**
Remove below lines from `app` file:

```
 android.sources {

        main {

            java {

                source {

                    srcDir "src"

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: failed to find buuild tools revision 22.0.1  ... i installed it but after finish install.. same error occured

Comment: same `'com.android.application' not found` error ? @aezaz

Comment: that error gone but failed to find build tools revision 22.0.1  error shows

Comment: Try other build version like 23.0.1 or 19 then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: this one error solved but in java file   for some opencv imports **import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
**           error is**cannot resolve symbol**

Comment: @aezaz you should accept answer if your above problem solved. For above import errors might be you are missing some library or forgetting to add `opencvlibrary310` library in your `app` project

Comment: answered accepted ....i have selected lib ... but all others lib working greatly but only few of them isn't working

Comment: that lib contains jni code and you have to compile jni code using ndk-build, did you done these things?

Comment: yes and it is like this  **C:\Users\Altaf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle**

Answer (score 0):

Change apply plugin: "com.android.application"
instead of apply plugin: "com.android.model.application" in **build.gradle(module:app)**

Comment: Rename application package name and try again

Comment: changed package name .... from android to andro no affect.... but apply:plugin:com.android.application is same

Comment: see this post and try again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795079/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750404/android-studio-error3-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found